# Can connect TRAMP with m-x ssh but can't with anything else (org code blocks, C-x C-f, etc.)

Tags: tramp, debugging

I have a very strange issue. I have no idea how to debug. TRAMP hangs every time I issue it via `C-x C-f` (and choose `ssh`), when I try to execute a org code block:

```
 :tangle:   /zeltak@aaa.zzz.yyy.xxx:/home/zeltak/.i3/config :mkdirp yes
```

but when I try to launch it with `M-x ssh` it does prompt me for a passwords and connects fine.

Any clue what can be going on?

Comment: Does this happen when you start Emacs using `emacs -Q`? If not, recursively bisect your init file to locate the problem. If yes, provide a step-by-step recipe to reproduce the problem, and state your platform, Emacs version, etc. IOW, provide an actionable question, please.

Comment: What is `M-x ssh`? I've never seen that before. What does `C-h f ssh RET` tell you about it?

Comment: hi. this is the output: ssh is an interactive autoloaded Lisp function in `ssh.el'.

(ssh INPUT-ARGS &optional BUFFER)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the 2 culprits and am reporting here for future use of anyone else. Following Drew's suggestion I spent a few hours binary partitioning my config and found 2 packages that interfered with proper tramp use:
`keychain-environment` and `dired-toggle-sudo`